# How to splice an array and add random numbers to each array index in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, vuejs3, splice

I am attempting to build a slot machine in JavaScript and Vue.js with the index of each array returning a random number. For this project, I am using a for loop to loop through a slot array initialized at `[1, 1, 1]`, and indexOf method to target the index of each slot array item. Then, I am also looping through an array of random numbers, then using a splice method to target the index of each slot array item, remove 1 element from that index, and replace the item at that given index with the random number. However, my `slots.value.splice(index, 1, randomNum[r])` setup appears to be removing 1 element at `index` and replacing that element with the last element of `randomNum` array. My intention is to instead replace the element at each index of `slots.value` with differing random numbers from the `randomNum` array. How can I go about doing this?

Here is my code:

```
<template>
  <div class="max-w-7xl mx-auto py-6 sm:px-6 lg:px-8">
    <div class="px-4 py-6 sm:px-0">
      <div  class="grid grid-cols-3 items-center py-16">
        <div v-for="slot in slots" :key="slot.id" class="w-96 h-96">
          <div class="w-full h-full rounded-md shadow-lg border-solid border-2 border-sky-500">
            <p class="text-9xl mt-28">{{ slot }}</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="flex justify-center">
        <button @click="spin">
          Spin
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>
import { ref } from "@vue/reactivity";

const slots = ref([1, 1, 1])

const spin = () => {
  const randomNumOne = Math.floor(Math.random() * (10 - 0) + 0)
  const randomNumTwo = Math.floor(Math.random() * (10 - 0) + 0)
  const randomNumThree = Math.floor(Math.random() * (10 - 0) + 0)

  const randomNum = [randomNumOne, randomNumTwo, randomNumThree]

  for (let i = 0; i < slots.value.length; i++) {
    for (let r = 0; r < randomNum.length; r++) {
      const index = slots.value.indexOf(slots.value[i])
      console.log(randomNum[r])
      if (index > -1) {
        // remove 1 element at each index and replace each with random numbers
        slots.value.splice(index, 1, randomNum[r])
      }
    }  
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this work for you ?

```js
const slots = [1, 1, 1]

const spin = () => {
  const randomNumOne = Math.floor(Math.random() * (10 - 0) + 0);
  const randomNumTwo = Math.floor(Math.random() * (10 - 0) + 0);
  const randomNumThree = Math.floor(Math.random() * (10 - 0) + 0);

  const randomNum = [randomNumOne, randomNumTwo, randomNumThree];

  for (let i = 0; i < slots.length; i++) {
    const index = Math.floor(Math.random() * randomNum.length);
    slots[i] = randomNum.splice(index, 1)[0];
  }
}

spin();
console.log(slots);
```

For each element of your `slots` array, we take a random element of `randomNum`, remove it and assign it to the current index of `slots`.

Note that you can have the same number appearing multiple times in the final `slots` since the generation of `randomNumOne`, `randomNumTwo` and `randomNumThree` doesn't prevent the same number from being generated more than once.

Comment: thanks for the feedback! Yes this works. Two questions: 1) For ```slots[i] = randomNum.splice(index, 1)[0]```, how does randomNum.splice return the spliced array element to ```slot[i]``` instead of returning the remaining non-spliced array elements? 2) what does adding [0] after the splice do?

Comment: The two questions are deeply linked!
The [doc for splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) states:
`Return value: An array containing the deleted elements. If only one element is removed, an array of one element is returned.`
So `randomNum.splice(index, 1)` removes 1 element from the array, and returns an array containing only this element. Since it's an array and we want only the value, we add `[0]` to get the first element.